# Ruby on Rails: some parameters of sessions are getting lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I've problem with sessions in Ruby on Rails: some parameters are getting lost between pages.
The problem is that it doesn't occur every time.

I'm using :active_record_store as a session storage in rails 3.2.9

To configure session_store I've added such line to /config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
PublicRor::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

I've had to use this kind of storage, because 4KB limit for cookie storage was too small for me.

Sample use case:

I'm storing data in session like this:

```
session[:some_key] = "some value"
```

And sometimes on next page views this this key doesn't occur (session contains various values, but not :some_key). 
The only solution to this problem that I've found is to clean sessions table manually (from sqlite browser), but guess that there're more clever ways :)

Is that is capacity of sessions array? Maybe it's getting overflowed?

What might be causing that error?

Comment: Can you attach REAL examples with real keys?

Comment: Does it only happen when 2 requests are handled simultaneously for the same user?